# Determine the time series process behind many different realizations

Tags: time-series, stochastic-processes

We have an unknown generator process. This could span from the simplest case of a Gaussian random walk to the most intricated and convoluted models you can think of. However, we don't know which is the process. The only thing we can observe is a dataset made of many realizations of this unknown process (for example, we could have the time index on the rows and the time series on the columns). Since the observations are aligned by rows due to the time index, this could be a piece of further information that can be used.

I would like to know what is the best tool to estimate the process that has generated the time series in the following cases:

1. we have a strong hypothesis about the process (e.g. an $\mathrm{ARMA}(p,q)$) and we would use the different realizations to make our parameters estimates more robust than what we would do with one time series;
2. we don't know whether all the time series belong to the same process generator, but we are able to estimate the parameters of a model of choice for each time series and we would need to build a single model that encompasses them all.

The final goal is short-term forecasting or, at least, a more accurate estimate of the last time series value without noise.

Some of my brainstorming:

- try to model the whole dataset as a $\mathrm{VARMA}(p,q)$ process, then forecast;
- try model each time series by using the same process, then make some inference on the distributions of the parameters to account for greater uncertainty;
- try to model the first principal component of the dataset as if it were a univariate time series;
- ...

Comment: In a "more accurate estimate of the last time series value without noise", what is *THE* time series? Are these noisy observations of the same underlying process (e.g. dynamics for $X_t$, observe $Y_t^{(i)} = X_t + \varepsilon_t^{(i)}$ and you want an estimate of $X_t$)? Or do you define the same dynamics for each $Y_t^{(i)}$, each of which is a realization of the same process, and you want to estimate their shared parameters (in which case the "estimate of the last time series value without noise" is just the expected value of the process at $t$)?

Comment: @ChrisHaug, the first one.